# Improving sphere detection in a bearing with opencv

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi4

Via a USB microscope on a RPI4,
I'm trying to check how many balls are on the image.
I'm trying with the `HoughCircles` solution and I have some results with tuning the parameters.
But I'm wondering if it's the right solution after an entire day of tuning

Via a USB microscope on a RPI4,
I'm trying to check if there are some balls (and how many of them are they) on the image.
I'm trying with the `HoughCircles` solution.
Another post helped me a lot.

- Medium results if the balls are sticked together (it detects 2 spheres, but not putting the center on the right place... And at the end I'll have 38 of them touching themselves in a micro-bearing ^^)

[image]
[image]

- No results with many balls in the bearing

[image]
[image]

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('/home/stephane/Documents/Bastien_Bearing/many_balls_in_bearing_with_light_good_side.jpg')

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blurred = cv2.medianBlur(gray, 25)

# # For 2 balls
# minDist = 10
# param1 = 9 
# param2 = 20 
# minRadius = 3
# maxRadius = 15

For many balls
minDist = 1
param1 = 9
param2 = 20 
minRadius = 1
maxRadius = 15

circles = cv2.HoughCircles(blurred, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, minDist, param1=param1, param2=param2, minRadius=minRadius, maxRadius=maxRadius)

if circles is not None:
    circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
    print("Nombre de cercles détectés:", len(circles[0]))
    for i in circles[0,:]:
        cv2.circle(img, (i[0], i[1]), i[2], (0, 255, 0), 2)
else:
    print("Aucun cercle détecté.")
    
cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Thanks a lot for any input/ideas :)
A good day to all in all cases !
Bastien

Edit :
With Mr. Rackwitz advice I'm trying to change the method,
Trying to find the local maximas without filtering.
The picture will not look a lot better :/ I need o use this cheap usb camera...
Without filtering so far no result, and bad results with a gray filter.

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
from skimage.feature import peak_local_max

# Load the image
img = cv2.imread('/home/stephane/Documents/Bastien_Bearing/many_balls_in_bearing_with_light_good_side.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# gray_blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (7, 7), 0)

# Find local maxima
coordinates = peak_local_max(gray, min_distance=20)

# Draw circles on potential spheres
for coord in coordinates:
    cv2.circle(img, (coord[1], coord[0]), 5, (0, 255, 0), 1)

print(f"Detected spheres: {len(coordinates)}")

# Show the result
cv2.imshow('Detected Spheres', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image: Local maximas (almost) no filter]

And I'm wondering if I should try to take advantage of the color putting a mask on the original image.
There are some results while not perfects at all :(
(Not all spheres found so far, and false positives. Maybe i just need to play longer with parameters)

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
from skimage.feature import peak_local_max

# Load the image
img = cv2.imread('/home/stephane/Documents/Bastien_Bearing/many_balls_in_bearing_with_light_good_side.jpg')

# Convert to HSV color space
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# Define the range of red color in HSV
lower_red = np.array([0, 120, 70])
upper_red = np.array([40, 255, 255])
mask1 = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_red, upper_red)

# Range for upper range
lower_red = np.array([130, 50, 70])
upper_red = np.array([200, 220, 235])
mask2 = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_red, upper_red)

# Generating the final mask to detect red color
mask =   mask2

# Bitwise-AND mask and original image
target = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=mask)

# Convert to grayscale for finding contours or local maxima
gray_target = cv2.cvtColor(target, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Optionally apply GaussianBlur to smooth the image and reduce noise
blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray_target, (5, 5), 0)

# Find local maxima
coordinates = peak_local_max(blurred, min_distance=20, threshold_abs=20)  

# Draw circles on detected spheres
for coord in coordinates:
    cv2.circle(img, (coord[1], coord[0]), 5, (0, 255, 0), 1)

print(f"Detected red spheres: {len(coordinates)}")

# Show the result
cv2.imshow('Detected Red Spheres', img)
cv2.imshow('Detected Red Spheres2', mask2)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image: Result with missing spheres and false positives]
[image: Result of the mask used]

Comment: thresholding? hough? bad approach. discard. -- pictures look bad. noisy, blurry, out of focus, and filtered to death by something (the camera or driver?). you should address that. -- make sure those are source images. unfiltered. no median blur. no filtering. no adjusting. -- get a decent point light source and shut out all other light. you'll get that light reflected in points on all the balls. those are local maxima. easily found. just make sure the light doesn't reflect on anything (into the camera) that you don't want to "see".

Comment: Thanks for you answer ! 
To be sure, no modifications on the image at all, directly searching local maximas ? 
I never tried this (yet), and was reading about it, but I found that some still use dilate (grayscale), and median blur (https://forum.opencv.org/t/locating-local-maximums/1534/2). 
Well, should try.

Comment: related: https://forum.opencv.org/t/detecting-balls-in-a-bearing/16685